# Maintaining a forked gem and forked dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, fork, bundler

I'm using a ruby project which consists of one main gem (let's call it SuperGem) and several smaller gems which it depends on. The project is on Github and I've forked it and am maintaining my own version (called SuperGemFork). When SuperGem is updated, I just need to pull and merge new code and then update the version number on SuperGemFork.

Now here's the situation. I also would like to make my own version of one of the dependencies (let's call it SmallGem). So now I want SuperGemFork to depend on SmallGemFork instead of SmallGem. So when both SuperGem and SmallGem are updated, I now have to pull and merge code from both gems into my forks, update the version numbers, and change the dependency in SuperGemFork to depend on the new version of SmallGemFork.

The problem I have is with having to change the dependency in SuperGemFork. When SuperGem (the original) is updated, it now depends on a new version of SmallGem. However, if I pull and merge the code from both gems, but then forget to update the dependency, the SuperGemFork is still dependent on the old version of SmallGemFork even though there is a new version available. Having to change the dependency is redundant and error-prone, and I would like to at least have something fail when I run `bundle install` or start the app if I forget to do so.

So, is there a nice way out there for me to easily maintain my own forks of gems which have dependencies between them?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible to monkey-patch the original gems, instead of rewriting the source code, I'd go that way. It's one of Ruby's strengths.

Then they can change their code and you won't be as closely coupled to physical layout of the source as you will the actual logic and the objects they're creating.

Comment: True, although then if I override a function in my version of the gem by monkey-patching but I only want to make a small change to the function, then I would essentially have to copy and paste the code from the original into my gem. Then when the function changes in the original gem, there's no easy way to detect that and merge the changes into my version. I really like the idea of monkey-patching as well because it makes dependencies much cleaner, but it seems like it would make development more difficult. What do you think?

Comment: In my experience, there is some code overlap when you monkey-patch, but it's a lot less than forking the entire gem. I think taking advantage of Ruby's ability to overwrite a method helps. It's not an easy task either way but you are ahead somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It looks like there are no other answers so I'll accept this one. It looks like it's either forking or monkey-patching, each of which have advantages and disadvantages.